# Is there a way to auto add reviewers to a GitHub pull request I make

Tags: github, automation, pull-request

I know there is a way to set auto reviewers for a repository through settings but I am in an organization with many repositories and members and can't change those settings.

My team specifically has 10 members. When I make a pull request in any of the orgs repos I add my team members as reviewers so I have to manually search 9 users and add them.

Repo default reviewers are only team leads and not for other devs so I can't change that setting to make my 9 members added by default as the hundreds of other PRs by various teams should not have us are reviewers.

There is a group made for my team and various other teams with all respective members however I have noticed that by adding the group as a reviewers all the members will get the PR in their review list but when any 1 of the member reviews the PR the approval is marked for the whole group and the PR goes away from active review list for the other members who might now have reviewed it yet.

Looking to see if there are user-specific settings that for my PRs it auto adds my 9 team members individually as reviewers on GitHub.

I can't make any repository or org level changes.

I have made a simple bash script that will add reviewers to PRs I have, however I think I jumped the gun and recreated the wheel. Is there a setting in GitHub that already does this.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it yet, but having the same problem and found this: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/auto-request-review. Depending on what you need, customize the workflow from its docs.